# Hibernate Envers creating modified fields for foreign owned OneToMany relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate 4.3.1.Final

If I have two Entities, let's say A and B.  A contains a set of B objects that is annotated as a `OneToMany` association.
If I set "org.hibernate.envers.global_with_modified_flag" to true and "org.hibernate.envers.modified_flag_suffix" to "Modified", then Envers correctly adds columns for the all of the columns in that table with the specified suffix, but it also expects to find a modified column for each of the associations even though they are owned by the foreign side.
In the below case, Envers expects columns in A for "foo" "fooModified", and "bObjectsModified" when I would think that it should expect columns for "foo" and "fooModified" in A and "aIdModified" in B.

```
@Entity
@Table("A")
@Audited
class A {
private String foo;
private Set<B> bObjects;

@Column(name = "foo")
public getFoo( return foo; )

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "a")
public Set<B> getBObjects() { return bObjects; }
}

@Entity
@Table("B")
@Audited
class B {
private A a;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "aId")
public getA(){ return a; }
}
```

Has anyone else seen this?  How do I change that behavior other than annotating every one of my `@ManyToOne` relationships with `@Audited(withModifiedFlag=false)`.  I have many thousands of relationships, so even testing that part will be a huge pain.
The alternative is forcing the database to know details about our Java code that it has no business knowing and makes it much more difficult to add bi-directional associations.

Answer (score 3):

For those who may come later, at least as of 4.3.1.Final, the only way to do this is to remove the global configuration flag and add that option to the `@Audited` annotation on every class so that it is `@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)` and then add `@Audited(withModifiedFlag=false)` to every property (not column!) in that class for which you do not want a modified field to be created.

In the other Hibernate modules, global configuration options can be overridden at the class or attribute level.  For Envers, global configuration options can never be overridden.

Also note that the modified field names are based on the attribute name in the Java class and not the value in the `@Column` annotation that the rest of Hibernate ORM uses.

Comment: Thanks for "Also note that the modified field names are based on the attribute name in the Java class and not the value in the Column annotation that the rest of Hibernate ORM uses." I was getting DuplicateMappingException using name value in Column annotation, and JPA would look up for the name value columns. Setting the naming.physical-stratergy to PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl solved the issue.